# Application not compatible from xcode 4.6 to xcode 5

Tags: ios7

I have a application which are make in xcode 4.6 when i open my application in xcode 5.0 then the title and backgrownd color will be white what should i do for looking in 5.0 as same as 4.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. in **Project Navigator** select ***Project***
2. in **Build Settings** set `Standard architectures (armv7, armv7s)` for Architectures
3. Then set **Deployment target** in *General tab* as `5.0`
4. at Last select **Main.Storyboard** set ***View as*** property to `iOS6.1 and Earlier` in ***File Inspector***
   also Uncheck `Use Autolayout`